# Vectors of Pointers passed into different functions

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I'm trying to practice with the usage of the new operator to create objects. I'm having some trouble with adjusting my code to manage the new pointers to the objects that I created.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct StudentRecord {
public:
    StudentRecord(
        string id,
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        int age,
        string phoneNumber,
        double gpa
    ) {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        Age = age;
        Gpa = gpa;
    }

    void display() {
        cout << "   Student ID: " << Id << endl;
        cout << "   First Name: " << FirstName << endl;
        cout << "    Last Name: " << LastName << endl;
        cout << " Phone Number: " << PhoneNumber << endl;
        cout << "          Age: " << Age << endl;
        cout << "          GPA: " << Gpa << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    string Id;
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    string PhoneNumber;
    int Age;
    double Gpa;

};

void displayStudents(vector<StudentRecord>& students) {

    for (auto student : students) {
        student.display();
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("TestFile.csv");
    string line = "";

    vector<StudentRecord> students;
    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {

        stringstream inputString(line);

        //StudentId, Last Name, FirstName, Age, Phone Number, GPA
        string studentId;
        string lastName;
        string firstName;
        int age;
        string phone;
        double gpa;
        string tempString;

        getline(inputString, studentId, ',');
        getline(inputString, lastName, ',');
        getline(inputString, firstName, ',');
        getline(inputString, tempString, ',');
        age = atoi(tempString.c_str());
        getline(inputString, phone, ',');
        getline(inputString, tempString);
        gpa = atof(tempString.c_str());

        students.push_back(new StudentRecord(studentId, lastName,firstName, age, phone, gpa));
        line = "";
    }

    displayStudents(students);
}
```

Specifically there's an issue here:

```
students.push_back(new StudentRecord(studentId, lastName,firstName, age, phone, gpa));
```

I know that I need to adjust the `displayStudents` function to take in a vector of pointers to the object, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<StudentRecord>>`. Your future self will thank you. (Otherwise it should have been `std::vector<StudentRecord*>`, but just don’t do that unless you (0) must and (1) understand all the implications.)

Comment: _I'm trying to practice with the usage of the new operator to create objects_ Why?  It's a method of last resort, usually only used with polymorphic objects (and even then, [`make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is to be preferred).

Comment: In addition to @PaulSanders 's comment, see the C++ core guideline R.11: [Avoid calling `new` and `delete` explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete).

Answer (score 2):

`students` is of type `vector<StudentRecord>`, therefore, you don't need to call `new`.

If you wanted to practice `new`, suggest changing it to `vector<StudentRecord*>`. Note that it's recommended to use a managed pointer type (e.g. `unique_ptr`, `smart_ptr`) instead of 'naked' pointers.

If you'd simply like to make the code work, use:

```
students.emplace_back(studentId, lastName,firstName, age, phone, gpa));
```

In either case, you might consider `std::move()` on locally-generated strings that you only use here, i.e., `std::move(studentId), std::move(lastName), ...` in the arguments of `emplace_back()` or `push_back()`.

Comment: Thanks! @lorro. I changed the code to vector<StudentRecord*> and it works now.

Comment: @AlexS.: Please accept the answer or indicate why it's not enough for you.